# Root genymotion devices

Tags: genymotion

I have added **`Samsung Galaxy S4`** using genymotion **`while I was using windows os`.** Now I'm using linux and added that device again. My problem is that the S4 is not rooted on my linux machine. I wonder if this is a bug ?
If it's not a bug can someone help me to root this device ?

Answer (score 6):

Genymotion devices are rooted by default.
For example start a device then type `adb shell` command. It will open a rooted shell:

```
root@vbox86p:/ # whoami
root
```

You can also manage the root access of your applications by opening `superuser` app through the apps launcher.

Comment: sir i run the command adb shell but i get error .. i really dont know why my genymotion device is not rooted by deafault.

Comment: If you want help you will need to provide more information. So please answer to all of these questions: how do you know the device is not rooted? Why do you want a rooted device? What is the error you get when running adb shell, please provide the logs. Post these answers on your question's post.